# Help to Determine the JQuery Plugin for this Modal Contact Form

Tags: jquery

I found a site with a very nice Modal Contact Form that I "think" is JQuery.

I've looked at this site: http://www.professional-painters.com/  with Firebug but I dont see the .js for this, so Im not sure how this is implemented.

I've seen some examples of good JQuery Modal Contact Forms like this one: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Another example illustrated the JQuery Modal and its use with PHP.  However, Im using ASP.NET 2.0 not PHP.  Does anyone know of something similar with ASP.NET C# and Ajax?

So if someone could give me the breakdown about how the Modal Contact Form is implemented for the Professional Painters site I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a ready made plugin and the code that does that is not even using jQuery (even though jQuery is present on the page).

You can find the code for it here:
http://www.professional-painters.com/js/motion.js

But that doesn't determine the look/feel of the contact form, so if you're looking for something that looks similar, you just need to copy the HTML + CSS

You can find the CSS for it here:
http://www.professional-painters.com/professional.css

Comment: Are you aware of a JQuery ready-made plugin that doesnt rely upon PHPmailer ?

Comment: I'm saying that the code that does that to the form is in motion.js, but it's not a "plugin", but custom javascript (and a bit bad at that).
Regarding a jquery plugin that doesn't rely on phpmailer, that is impossible, because contact forms always need a server to send the actual emails. phpmailer (or using the mail()) function in php are the easiest methods for people to get that up and running

Comment: Yea Im so used to the C# functionality.  ok well the motion.js and code doesnt run, Im going to repost with the code.

Comment: someone else mentioned to re-factor the php to C#, but I've never even seen php.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a modal per say.  I'd describe it more as drop down navigation.  There is a div on the page id=quickcontact that by default is set to hidden.  When you click the "Quick Contact" icon that div is displayed.

Not really a modal, more of CSS drop down navigation using onclick instead of onhover.

Modals in general are all CSS and JS the backend is really up to you.